# Calculating center of polygon having matrix with it's points

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, polygon

I have a matrix in matlab contains  x, y of points of a polygon
I want to find the  center of the polygon defined by this points
e.g. :

```
[ 0 0 ; 0 1 ; 1 1 ; 1 0  ]
```

I need to find its center.

Comment: There is no built-in for this. Check out [this submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/319-polygeom-m)

Comment: you can call mean to find center of polygon's points.

Comment: Depends of your definition of "The center of the polygon" as well.